# React JS filter

Tags: reactjs, api

I am trying to show values by types, but it return only one value

```
  filerBuilding(value) {
    this.state.buildings.map((item) => {
      if (value.target.value === item.buildingType) {
        this.setState({
          buildings: this.state.buildings.splice(this.state.buildings.length),
        });
        let data = [];
        data.push(item);
        this.setState({ buildings: data });
      }
      else{
        
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: You create the `data` array inside the `map`, so every time you find a value you overwrite it with the new value; try to declare it before the `map` and pass it to the state at the end of the `map` function

Comment: @Giacomo and second question. When i choose another option, page still showing me values from first option, how can i fix it?

Answer (score 0):

@Giacomo's comment addresses the issue. To translate it into an implementation using `filter`:

```
function filterBuilding(value) {
  const filtered = this.state.buildings.filter(
    item => value.target.value === item.buildingType
  );

  this.setState({ buildings: filtered });
}
```